# Trying to print a mesage based on the time of day using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is The script I am tring to use, but nothing shows up on the web page.  I've tested some basic scripts to make sure it is linked correctly and it is.

```
var date, time;
date = new Date();
time = date.getHours();

if (time > 0 && time < 6){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning, you must ba an early bird!";
} else if (time >= 6 && time < 12){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning";
} else if (time >= 12 && time < 18){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon";
} else if ((time <= 18 )&& (time < 0)) {
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Evening"
}
```

Comment: Just use ``else {...}`` instead of ``else if ((time <= 18 )&& (time < 0)){...}``

Comment: Just tried that and no dice, it has to be executing something but just not printing it.  if i add `document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Evening";` outside the if statement it works so i know it is linked to the page. But when i tried to add the else statment that you suggested nothing happened.

Comment: try put `debugger` before `if` statements and make sure you are running this script correctly.

Comment: it says date.getHours() is not a constructor.

Comment: `time = new date.getHours();`
remove `new` so it should be `time = date.getHours();`

Comment: so that removes the error but stilll doesnt work

Comment: let me know your html for "WelcomeMessage"

Comment: `<p id = "WelcomeMessage"></p>` That's the html for it, like i said I can get the message to print something but only outside the if statment.

Comment: I also just tried this `if (true){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning, you must ba an early bird!";
}` to see if any if statment worlked and it worked fine.

Comment: Question can time be `else if (time >= 18 && time < 0)` be greater than 18 but also at the same time be less than 0? I think your last line should be `else if (time >= 18)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const date = new Date();
const time = date.getHours();

if (time > 0 && time < 6){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning, you must ba an early bird!";
} else if (time >= 6 && time < 12){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning";
} else if (time >= 12 && time < 18){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon";
} else {
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Evening"
}
```

Comment: this is correct solution! if you have a problem, i can help you via teamviewer

Comment: Okay, I got it. That works.  Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make small change with your code and its working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="WelcomeMessage"></p>

<script>

var date, time;
date = new Date();
time = date.getHours();

if (time > 0 && time < 6){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning, you must ba an early bird!";
} else if (time >= 6 && time < 12){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Morning";
} else if (time >= 12 && time < 18){
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon";
} else if ((time <= 18 )&& (time < 0)) {
    document.getElementById("WelcomeMessage").innerHTML = "Good Evening"
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that still doesn't work for me.  what does ".value" do?